# Link to a non-secure website from a secure website

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl

We have a website with different languages, I handle the website for German and US English, while Polish, UK English etc. are handled by the other team overseas.

To get to the point the website I handle are secure with verified SSL certificates, while the other language websites are not.

So when the customer is trying to switch the language, he gets a warning saying the website is not secure.

I want to be able to redirect from our secure website to insecure website without this warning. Is it possible to do so?